# Need to set value=1 when checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following is a function that post the values and updation takes place in db according to funcion.But now according to this even if its checked or not checked ,updation doesnt takes place ,ie it returns value 0.

I need to set value as 1 if input is checked and post it too .Is it possible?

```
<!--HTML part-->

<input type="checkbox" id="gi25" onClick=" print_yes(25,9)" checked="checked">

<!--Jquery part-->

  function print_yes(id,uid)
        {
        var val=$('#gi'+id).val();
                    $.ajax(
    {
    type : 'POST',
    url  : 'custom_ajax.php',
    data : 'cmd=greeninfo&id1='+val+'&uid='+uid+'&id2='+id,                         
    dataType : 'json',
    success : function(data)
    {


    }                       

    });                                                 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="checkbox" id="gi25" onClick=" print_yes(25,9)" checked="checked" value="1">
```

You do not currently have a value set for that checkbox

EDIT per OP's comment:

```
<!--HTML part-->

<input type="checkbox" id="gi25" onClick=" print_yes(25,9)" checked="checked">

<!--Jquery part-->

function print_yes(id,uid)
{
    var val=$('#gi'+id).attr('checked') ? 1 : 0;
    $.ajax(
    {
    type : 'POST',
    url  : 'custom_ajax.php',
    data : 'cmd=greeninfo&id1='+val+'&uid='+uid+'&id2='+id,                         
    dataType : 'json',
    success : function(data)
    {


    }                       

    });                                                 
}
```

Comment: actually its based on condition,ie it takes result from database and shows here, I have shown it simply... so user need to edit this result. if I set the value as 1 then it returns the value 1 only, need to update database according to this value.... if value is 0 then answer field in database must be 0 if value is 1 then answer field in database must be 1

Comment: @Authman: Dont use attr for 'checked' attribue.See this, http://api.jquery.com/prop/.

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign value to checkbox on the basis of whether its checked or not.

```
 function print_yes(id, uid) {
 var checkbox = $('#gi' + id);
 var val;
 if (checkbox.prop('checked')) {
     val = '1';
 } else {
     val = '0';
 }

 $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: 'custom_ajax.php',
     data: 'cmd=greeninfo&id1=' + val + '&uid=' + uid + '&id2=' + id,
     dataType: 'json',
     success: function (data) {


     }

 });
 }
```

Comment: its entering the else part.... i have checked and unchecked... both gives result 0

Comment: now after refresh showing an error checkbox.prop is not a function

Comment: Dont use attr for 'checked' attribue.See this, http://api.jquery.com/prop/. You should use the latest jQuery.